# Need explanation on Maatwebsite Excel "From View" code

Tags: netbeans-8, maatwebsite-excel

While researching on how I can import table listing data using collection + HTML view to an excel file, I came across [maatwebsite/excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package. I managed to import the excel by following the documentation. However, I am not familiar with the code syntax used by the author. On [this link](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/from-view), the author defines a function view() as seen in the code below:

```
public function view(): View
{
    return view('exports.invoices', [
        'invoices' => Invoice::all()
    ]);
}
```

I am not familiar with **view(): View** syntax. Can someone direct me to a proper documentation for this? And tell me how I can resolve this in Netbeans (See screenshot below)?
[Screenshot of Netbeans error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt1DT.png)

Please keep in mind, the code itself is working correctly and has no issues. I am able to download the excel file as per my requirements.

Using: Laravel 5.6, PHP 7.1.17, NetBeans 8.0.2, maatwebsite/excel 3.0

Any info on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 7.0 and greater, we can define the return type. For example.

```
function sum(): int {
// function body.

}
```

And same goes for:

> public function view(): View

This line says that the function view() only returns the View class object.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your explanation I found the documentation for it.
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration